# Flutter: Is the official documentation for align wrong?

Tags: flutter, alignment

When I was reading through Align's documentation I found the following explanation.

[image]

The link is https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html#widgets.Align.2

The 0.2 is the xAlign and the 0.6 is the YAlign, follow the formulas in the official documentation and finally calculate a point `(36.0,48.0)`. When xAlign is less than zero or yAlign is less than zero, the calculation according to this formula is always positive. And the formula for calculating the offset of `FlutterLogo` and `Container` in the source code is as follows(`alignment.dart` `lines:290`):

```
Offset other = size - child!.size as Offset;
final double centerX = other.dx / 2.0;
final double centerY = other.dy / 2.0;
childParentData.offset = Offset(centerX + xAlign * centerX, centerY + yAlign * centerY);
```

The result according to the formula in the source code does not seem to have any relation to `(36,48)`. Did I misunderstand or did the document say something wrong?

Comment: they are right: they say about 2 points: *"The alignment property describes **a point** in the child's coordinate system and **a different point** in the coordinate system of this widget. The Align widget positions the child such that both points are lined up on top of each other."* - `childParentData.offset` is a result of that positioning and is different from those two above virtual points

Answer (score 1):

The calculation formula is correct. You have to bear in mind that the centre for image object is (0,0) which is the top-left corner of the object and not the centre of the object. So you have to take into consideration the size of the object.

```
final double centerX = (other.dx + child.size.width) / 2.0;
final double centerY = (other.dy + child.size.height) / 2.0;
```

I might not be doing the maths right but, the idea is to move the (0,0)-centre position of the child from top-left to centre.